# How to write a brief author biography for a journal article?

Tags: publications

One of my papers has recently been accepted!
We received an e-mail informing us that
we have a short time frame in which we need to do a bunch of work
to get the paper ready for publication.
In particular, one of the components which we need to submit is
a brief author biography for each co-author.

I have had a few papers published before,
but none of these papers has required me
to provide a brief author biography.
What information should I include in this biography?
Can someone provide a sample of his/her biography
for me to use as a reference or template?

Comment: Can't you look at author biographies from other papers *in that journal*?

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy Now that you mention it, that does seem to be the best approach. I wonder why I hadn't thought of that. Could you submit this comment as an answer?

Comment: Certainly -- glad to be of help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you look at author biographies from other papers in *that journal*?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks what information should be included and you've just pointed to a resource that would allow the asker to answer their own question. IMO, this was correctly posted as a comment and shouldn't have been reposted as an answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby While this isn't a real "answer", I decided to accept because other papers in the same journal is the best source of author biographies for me to copy from.

Answer (score 3):

My experience in this field is the next.

1. Bio should include main things dealing with you as a researcher:

   - name
   - university and specialty that you graduated
   - your current position
   - awards
   - scientific interests
2. Usualy, it have to be a very-very short version of your bio (several sentences).